# disabling javascript from overriding breadcrumb navigation styling

Tags: javascript, css, breadcrumb

I've used some CSS to restyle the titlebar breadcrumbs in a SharePoint 2010 mysite.

```
.s4-title h1 a, .s4-title h2 a, .s4-titlesep h2, .s4-title h2, .ms-ltviewselectormenuheader .ms-viewselector a
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #777777;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.s4-title h1 a:hover, .s4-title h2 a:hover, .ms-ltviewselectormenuheader .ms-viewselector a:hover
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #454545;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This gives me menus that look exactly like I want them to.  And they underline and go darker as required when you hover over them (sorry not enough rep to show the image)
[image]

However, some SharePoint javascript is overriding my efforts when I navigate to a document library such as Dave Hooper > Share Documents > All Documents and hover over the 'all documents' link:
[image]

I presume the styling is changing due to some built in javascript as disabling it makes it behave like the 'Shared Documents' links.  But obviously the site needs javascript and I still want the popup to appear and allow users to change views etc.

So I presume I need to override some Javascript somehow?  Any ideas?

Thanks @dandroid and @sig-weber!
In the end I had to do a little more work (should I put the complete answer in a comment or is editing my original post the right thing to do?) but @sig-weber did the hard work:

```
.ms-ltviewselectormenuheader .ms-viewselectorhover
{
    border: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0 0 0px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.ms-ltviewselectormenuheader .ms-viewselectorhover A
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #454545;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    background-image: none;
    padding: 2px 0 0 0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 6px;
}
```

Comment: You could just override that styling as well. Doesn't hurt the functionality by doing so. No need to change any javascript

Comment: I assumed (I may be wrong as I'm a n00b at SharePoint and Javascript after coming from a pure ASP.NET and SQL background) that the javascript is happening AFTER I've styled it in CSS - it all works fine with Javascript disabled.  So how can I override it?

Comment: The JavaScript applies some CSS styles which are defined in the core.css which is easily overridden by any other css if you css is loaded after the core.css.

Comment: ah right - thanks for the clarification.  I'll go hunting in core.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharePoint built-in JavaScript changes the CSS class, so you need to apply your style like this:

```
.ms-viewselectorhover a
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #454545;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: In the end I needed:  

.ms-ltviewselectormenuheader .ms-viewselectorhover
{
 border: 0px;
 padding: 2px 0 0 0px;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.ms-ltviewselectormenuheader .ms-viewselectorhover A
{
 font-family: Verdana;
 color: #454545;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 10pt;
 text-decoration: underline !important;
 background-image: none;
 padding: 2px 0 0 0px;
 margin: 0 0 0 6px;
}